# When I try to divert standard output with System.Diagnostics.Process, the called program gives an error

Tags: vb.net

To summarise the following: If I use `Process` to call WinZip, WinZip performs its task correctly but I lose the console output.  If I divert the standard output, I get that output but WinZip fails to create a zip file and reports “FATAL ERROR: win32/windows system error (print.cpp@315): The handle is invalid.”  Can anyone identify my error?

I have a security system written in Excel VBA.  It identifies files to archive and uses batch files to call the command line interface of WinZip and maintains an index within an Excel worksheet.  This system has served me well for many years but it had some deficiencies that I believed would be solved by recoding with VB.Net.

The VB.Net version was more of a port than a recode and I maintained the use of batch files.  The new versions solved most of the deficiencies with the VBA version but one remained.

Within a batch file, a file name must be strictly ASCII to avoid problems.  Most of my file names are ASCII but a few are not, for example: “009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg”.  This is a photograph from a holiday in Norway where I have included the name of the town in the file name.  Within batch files, hexadecimal C5 is sometimes treated as Unicode (display value Å) and sometimes as code page 437 (display value ┼).  I suspect what is passed to a program is the UTF-8 code for hexadecimal C5 split into two bytes to give C3 85.  Whatever is happening, no program called via a batch file can find file “009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg”.

I avoided this problem with the VBA solution by checking filenames for non-ASCII characters.  If found, the processing would be of the form:

- VBA macro renames file “009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg” as “009 $C5lesund - Art Deco tower.jpg”.
- Batch file calls WinZip to zip file “009 $C5lesund - Art Deco tower.jpg”.
- VBA macro renames file “009 $C5lesund - Art Deco tower.jpg” as “009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg”.
- VBA macro records both the correct name and the name under which it had been archived in the index.

Although this was messy, it worked and was the best I could think of.

I have implemented the same approach with VB.Net but I have been looking for a better alternative.

I use `Shell` to execute the batch file so I first investigated using `Shell` to call WinZip directly rather than via a batch file.  WinZip outputs progress and error information to the console which I redirect to text file “zip.txt” using `ZipCommand > zip.txt`.  I thoroughly check for possible error conditions prior to creating the batch file so I rarely get error messages but I would prefer not to give up access to WinZip’s console output.  I cannot discover any method of diverting console output using `Shell`.

I then tried `Process` which appears to offer the functionality I seek but I am encountering an error.

The code below was intended as proof-of-concept.  Within it there are three statements that are currently commented out:

```
  '1 .RedirectStandardOutput = True
  '2 .UseShellExecute = False
  '3 zipOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

If I run the code as is with the file to be zipped missing, the process finishes with exit code 12.  WinZip’s error codes are not published and its documentation claims only exit code 0 meaning “no errors” is reliable.

If I run the code as is with the file to be zipped present, the process finishes with exit code 0.  The zip file is formed correctly.

I get appropriate exception errors if statement 3 is enabled by removing “'3” or if both statements 1 and 3 are enabled.  However, if I run the code with all three statements enabled I get exit code 254 and the zip file is not created.  The diverted console output is:

```
WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 32-bit (Build 10562)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved

using encryption AES-256

FATAL ERROR: win32/windows system error (print.cpp@315): The handle is invalid.


Program is terminating!

Please send the file wzCLine.rpt to the address below.

To help solve this problem, please include as detailed as possible
a description of what you were doing before the problem occurred,
so we can try to reproduce the problem here.

WinZip Computing
EMail: support@winzip.com
Web: http://www.winzip.com
```

The file “wzCLine.rpt” contains:

```
Please send the file wzCLine.rpt to the address below.

To help solve this problem, please include as detailed as possible
a description of what you were doing before the problem occurred,
so we can try to reproduce the problem here.

WinZip Computing
EMail: support@winzip.com
Web: http://www.winzip.com

FATAL ERROR: win32/windows system error (print.cpp@315): The handle is invalid. 
Output_context_info: 528d4140
Return address = 0000000a

Windows NT 6.0 build 6002 Service Pack 2

Current date/time: 01/02/2016 14:56
WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On (10562cl)
Build 10562
Module name = c:\Program files\WinZip\wzzip.exe
Command line: <"c:\Program files\WinZip\wzzip.exe" -a -s"12345678" -ycAES256  -whs "C:\Secure\Temp\test.zip" "C:\Secure\Temp\009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg">
Memory in use = 61%
Total physical memory = 2097151 Kbytes
Physical memory available = 1199000 Kbytes
Total virtual memory = 2097024 Kbytes
Virtual memory available = 2035664 Kbytes
Country code: 44 Language: English Code-page: 1252

[eof]
```

I will probably send a report to WinZip.com but I assume the cause is an error in my use of `Process` and not an error within WinZip.

Any advice on how to avoid the error and/or improve my code will be gratefully received.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                            Handles btnExit.Click

    Me.Close()

  End Sub
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                         Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Process, ProcessStartInfo and ProcessWindowStyle within namespace System.Diagnostics
    ' Threading within namespace System

    Dim proc As Process = Nothing
    Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim zipOutput As String = ""

    Dim zipArguments As String = "-a -s""12345678"" -ycAES256  -whs ""C:\Secure\Temp\test.zip""" & _
                                 " ""C:\Secure\Temp\009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg"""

    With procInfo
      .Arguments = zipArguments
      .FileName = "c:\Program files\WinZip\wzzip.exe"
      '1 .RedirectStandardOutput = True
      '2 .UseShellExecute = False
      .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
    End With

    Dim endTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 30, Now())
    Dim finished As Boolean = False

    Try
      proc = Process.Start(procInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception
      lblMsg.Text = "Unable to start process: " & ex.Message
      Exit Sub
    End Try

    If proc.HasExited Then
      ' The started process may have activated an existing instance of itself and then exited.
      Debug.Assert(False)
    End If

    ' Pause until process has exited or timed out
    Do While True
      '3 zipOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
      Debug.Print("Sleep")
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
      If proc.HasExited Then
        finished = True
        Exit Do
      End If
      If Now() > endTime Then
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop

    If finished Then
      lblMsg.Text = "Process finished with exit code " & proc.ExitCode
    Else
      Try
        proc.Kill()
        lblMsg.Text = "Process did not terminate so I killed it"
      Catch ex As Exception
        lblMsg.Text = "Process did not terminate and my attempt to kill it failed."
      End Try
    End If

    lblMsg.Text &= vbLf & zipOutput

    Debug.Print(lblMsg.Text)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you considered renaming the file(s)?  If the mish mash of actors involved can handle the same file(s) with scrubbed names, you'd have an idea how to solve it.

Comment: @Plutonix Renaming the files is the approach I have used successfully for some years. I was looking for a better approach. Without the redirection, I can run WinZip successfully using `Process` which appears (as one would expect) to be much faster than using `Shell`to run a batch file to run WinZip. I may decide loosing the console output is a price worth paying for the other advantages.  However, if I learn how to use `Process`'s redirection correctly that would be much better.

Comment: Probably a daft thing to ask, but is there a reason why you cant use the built in zip handling in VB?

Comment: @DavidWilson.  Definitely not daft. The current system is a port from VBA and relies heavily on WinZip and its console output. Continuing to use WinZip without involving batch file would be the least disruptive update. Even if I switch to the `ZipFile` class, I would like to know why I am unable to use `Process` and `RedirectStandardOutput`.

Comment: Sorry - cant help there. I would think that as nobody else has replied with an answer, It is wzzip that is the problem. Hope you get joy from WinZipFolks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Try this.

```
' Pause until process has exited or timed out
zipOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
proc.WaitForExit()
lblMsg.Text = "Process finished with exit code " & proc.ExitCode
lblMsg.Text &= vbLf & zipOutput
```

I'm not sure exactly why you're getting the invalid handle error, but it might be something to do with this excerpt from msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm guessing that adding the **Proc.WaitForExit** makes your code wait until the previous **zipOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()** has finished working.

> The redirected StandardOutput stream can be read synchronously or
>   asynchronously. Methods such as Read, ReadLine, and ReadToEnd perform
>   synchronous read operations on the output stream of the process. These
>   synchronous read operations do not complete until the associated
>   Process writes to its StandardOutput stream, or closes the stream.

Full Code Here -

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                            Handles btnExit.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
                         Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Process, ProcessStartInfo and ProcessWindowStyle within namespace System.Diagnostics
        ' Threading within namespace System

        Dim proc As Process = Nothing
        Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim zipOutput As String = ""

        Dim zipArguments As String = "-a -s""12345678"" -ycAES256  -whs ""C:\Secure\Temp\test.zip""" &
                                 " ""C:\Secure\Temp\009 Ålesund - Art Deco tower.jpg"""

        With procInfo
            .Arguments = zipArguments
            .FileName = "c:\Program files\WinZip\wzzip.exe"
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        End With

        Dim endTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 30, Now())
        Dim finished As Boolean = False

        Try
            proc = Process.Start(procInfo)
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblMsg.Text = "Unable to start process: " & ex.Message
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        If proc.HasExited Then
            ' The started process may have activated an existing instance of itself and then exited.
            Debug.Assert(False)
        End If

        ' Pause until process has exited or timed out
        zipOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        proc.WaitForExit()
        lblMsg.Text = "Process finished with exit code " & proc.ExitCode
        lblMsg.Text &= vbLf & zipOutput

        Debug.Print(lblMsg.Text)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts (+1) but your solution does not work for me. My problem may be that I have an old laptop with Windows Vista and the latest versions of some packages claims to no longer support Vista even though they seem to work for me. In particular, I have the latest version of WinZip. I will be replacing my laptop soon so I will leave this attempted upgrade of my security system until I have. I suspect you are in the right area. I was worried by MS's warnings about deadlocks between the application and the directed output. I hope I can accept your answer in a month or two.

Comment: Hmm. I ran the code on my pc and got the wzzip out up in the form. All I changed was the directory of the source folder and the new code replacing the old code I think.  If I get time I'll post all the code before I turn in

Comment: What version of. Net and vb are you using?  Also what errors did you get?

Comment: I am using VB 2010 and Net 4.0.  As I have said my laptop is old and I cannot upgrade some software until I update the OS which will require a clean install. I am relunctant to wipe my hard drive in case I find my laptop doesn't support Windows 10 or doesn't have enough memory for it to run efficiently.

Comment: Unfortunately, your full code did not help.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with Windows 10 - It might be worth googling your laptop and Windows 10 to  see what (if any) problems other users have had.